# how to use csrf token asp c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've started with asp mvc 3, with c# and razor, then. I want to use forms with security for send petitions POST.

I want to with razor render some like that

```
<form action="/sass/" method="post">
     @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Ingresa tu Nombre</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="nombre" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar mi duda" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" />
        </div>
     }
```

And in C# I dont know how to validate that csrf token, is valid.
I work with C#, asp mvc3 and razor.

Please help me!

Answer (score 3):

In your action method you need to add the respective attribute **[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]**, and it validate the input for you.

Comment: if this answer was useful for you, please Accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem with the state of your code. There are two embedded forms: the outer one and the one produced by `Html.BeginForm`. However, the way to validate the token is to decorate the target action or controller with `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`.

So either:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

or to validate **all** methods in the controller:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public class MyController : Controller
{
}
```

Comment: How to I should put my form with params free, so: <form action="something", method="post" class="someclass">. It using Html.BeginForm()

Comment: As I learned today, there is a difference between AntiForgeryToken and CsrfToken. Csrf is more restrictive than AntiForgery. But nevertheless attributes are still the way to go.